# How can I have the id of an li added by 1 when a button is clicked.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button which adds a li to a div. I want the id of the li to be added by 1. Like if my id of the first li is 1 I want the next one to be 2 and so on. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the easiest thing to do would be to keep a global counter var in your script file to store how many li elements you have. You can then set that to be your id and increment it for the next time.
e.g.

```
<script>
var counter = 0;

$('div#id').click(function(){
    counter = counter + 1;
    var newDiv = counter;
});
</style>;
```

Failing that, I'd be using `$("div#id").children().last().attr('id');` to find the last element's ID and then increment it.

Comment: Both of these allow you to set the starting point, but @gknicker's answer seems simpler if you're always starting from 1.

Comment: I dont understand can you explain the first method?

Comment: Added some sample code

Answer (score 3):

Count the `li` elements in the div using the [`length` property](http://api.jquery.com/length).

```
var nextID = $('#mydivID li').length + 1;
```

Comment: Believe you can also use .length if you prefer vanilla js

Comment: @plushyObject Thanks, I actually found out the `size()` method has been deprecated, so I updated my answer to use the `length` property instead.

Comment: Sweet! I feel loved.